# How can I set the Android accordion view to be initially expanded?

Tags: android, accordion

I am using the [android-accordion-view](https://github.com/hamsterready/android-accordion-view) library. You can change the items in the view by editing `accordion_sections`:

```
 <string-array name="accordion_sections">
        <item>Section A</item>
        <item>Section B</item>
        <item>Section C</item>
        <item>Section D</item>
        <item>Section E</item>
 </string-array>
```

I want to make sure that every item in the view is initially in the expanded state. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are asking, but to my knowledge it is better to place the listview in linearlayout (which you might have done already) and then make the visibility of that layout to be true. So that when your app is been launched every item would be in the expanded state. And further changes in the expansion state can be done using source file which you might have already known.